# required for input parameters on swagger

Tags: rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

when I use `@RequestParam` with `required = true` on rest and while  testing this on swagger, it will be shown along with ***required** mark next to it.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getinfo")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMyInfo(@RequestParam(value = "input", required = true)  int input, other request parameters)
```

But now how can I achieve same on swagger if i have mapped url with object using `@ModelAttribute` .

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getinfo")
        public ResponseEntity<?> getMyInfo(@ModelAttribute MyObject myObject)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the annotation `@ApiParam`

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getinfo")
public ResponseEntity<?> getMyInfo(@ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject)
```

Inside your MyObject class

```
public class MyObject {

  private long id;

  @ApiParam(name = "name", value = "Name is Mandatory", required = true)   
  private String name;

}
```

Now, `name` will be a ***required** field.

Comment: But not all all properties inside MyObject are required. I want to set required only to some properties only